# Ember.js browser support?

Tags: html, cross-browser, ember.js

Is there a documented list of desktop browsers and versions which support Ember.js apps? That is, if I say an app developed in Ember.js will support IE 9+, FF 11+, Chrome 17+, Safari 5+, will I be overreaching or underreaching? If support is fluid, what does it depend on?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When doing new releases we run tests across all [platforms available on BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms). We have a couple test failures on some of the older platforms, but in practice they all do work. The biggest concern if you support older versions of IE is performance. However, it should still work properly. It definitely supports all modern browsers and mobile platforms, though built in touch support is limited.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! Glad to be using this stuff again, even if I have to get back in the flow...

Comment: http://travis-ci.org/ - it [mostly] works in IE6, but doesn't in IE7 and IE8. Is it a problem of Ember or theirs?

Comment: @gshilin I suspect this is a problem limited to Travis. If you can demonstrate a problem with Ember itself, please file it as a bug, since we do intend for it to work.

Comment: @PeterWagenet - thanks! btw, this info would be really useful on the about page; it's a pretty core bit of info on any JS library.

Comment: Hello Peter, do you have any information about Mobile Browsers support for Ember.js?Thanks

Comment: @PeterWagenet - hello since this reply is a few years old, can I ask if Ember 1.x still supports IE7 (I am aware that 2.0 will drop IE8)? Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

[It has been announced](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/04/20/ie8-support-update.html) that Ember 2.0 will support IE9+, and that the 1.13.x series will be the last version to support IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

**Browser Supportability For Ember 2.x**

Base on the Github README, https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/

The following browsers versions are supported.

[image]