# Detect whether a browser supports Ember.js

Tags: browser, ember.js

I want to detect whether a browser supports the Ember.js library. If not, I will show users a message to let them download the latest version of their browser. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873744/ember-js-browser-support) contributed by an Ember.js core team member.

In it, he states that the majority of the browsers on [browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com) are supported, meaning they do thorough testing.

Rather than show the message based on a functionality test of the user's browser each time they load your application, I suggest you instead build a list of known incompatible browsers (anything older than what is on BrowserStack would be a good start) and expand it based on monitoring your access logs or reported issues from the likely minority users on unsupported browsers.

That "blacklist" approach would serve most efficient, as Ember.Js and other libraries like jQuery are usually designed to continually support all new browsers.